# Invalid Procedure call or argument on Debug.Print

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to redo a function I made a few days ago using some advice I received on here...I get an Invalid Procedure call or argument on the line with Debug.Print.

Very new to VBA and Excel. Thanks for your help and patience.

```
Public Sub GetSOPFiles()
    ' Set folder path
    Const FolderPath As String = "C:\Users\test\Desktop\SOP Excel Prototype"

    Const FileExt As String = "docx"

    Dim Result As Variant
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim MyFile As Object
    Dim MyFSO As Object
    Dim MyFolder As Object
    Dim MyFiles As Object
    Dim dept As Variant
    Dim deptCodes As Variant

    Set MyFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set MyFolder = MyFSO.GetFolder(FolderPath)
    Set MyFiles = MyFolder.Files

    Dim vData As Variant
    Dim sTemp As Variant

    ReDim vData(0 To MyFiles.Count - 1, 0 To 0)

    x = 1

    With MyFiles
        While x <= UBound(vData, 1)
            Debug.Print (MyFiles(x).Name)
        Wend
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: `ReDim vData(0 To MyFiles.Count - 1, 0 To 0)` why 0 to 0?

Comment: Not sure why, it was something that was suggested by someone else on here. I just removed it but I am still getting the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MyFiles` is a collection and should be iterated over with a `For Each...Next` loop.

```
Set MyFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set MyFolder = MyFSO.GetFolder(FolderPath)
Set MyFiles = MyFolder.Files

For Each MyFile In MyFiles
    Debug.Print MyFile.Name ' no parentheses
Next
```

You can't index into the `MyFiles` collection. Use a `For Each...Next` loop, as the [`Files` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/files-collection) explains.

Comment: Yes, I had my file like that originally. Someone suggested that a With/End statement would be faster than a For Each. What are your thoughts?

Comment: `With...End With` is not a loop. `While...Wend` is more or less deprecated. This is a simple case for `For...Each` loop. If you're concerned about speed, perhaps read https://analystcave.com/vba-for-loop-vs-for-each-loop/.

Comment: As another point - even if `MyFiles(x)` were valid syntax, you currently have an infinite loop...